# Убрать всё, что между парами квадратных скобок

Tags: регулярные-выражения, dart

Есть строка вида "abc[a]NEED TO REMOVE THIS[a]some text[b]AND THIS[b]". Необходимо убрать всё, что заключено между парами квадратных скобок. Знаю, что решением является что-то на подобии этого: `myString.replaceAll(RegExp('[*]*[*]', '')`, но не знаю как правильно сделать регулярку.

Comment: Сами маркеры `[a][/a]` должны оставаться на своих местах, или же тоже удаляться вместе с содержимым?

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/fj5MeD/1

Comment: я не знаю, какой у вас движок для regex, но если он умеет Lookbehind, и вместо a и b всегда один символ, то то, что я выше привел,  будет работать

Comment: @splash58 поддерживается но не полностью, ваш пример не сработает.

Comment: Какой текст вам нужен в результате? Если у вас `abc[a]NEED TO REMOVE THIS[a]some text[b]AND THIS[b]`, то нужен `abc[a][a]some text[b][b]`? Тогда ответ у меня уже есть. Если нужно получить `abcsome text`, всё ещё проще: `text.replaceAll(RegExp(r'\[(\w+)][^]*?\[\1]'), '')`

Comment: Да, маркеры тоже нужно убрать. Извиняюсь за неправильную постановку задачу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если нужно удалить всё вместе с тегами, вы можете использовать [`String#replaceAll`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.1/dart-core/String/replaceAll.html)

```dart
String result = text.replaceAll(RegExp(r'\[(\w+)][^]*?\[\1]'), '');
```

См. [пример работы выражения](https://regex101.com/r/ng2d9b/1). **Подробности**:

- `\[`  - символ `[`
- `(\w+)` - Подмаска №1: одна и более букв, цифр или `_`
- `]` - символ `]`
- `[^]*?` - ноль и более любых символов, но как можно меньше
- `\[\1]` - `[`, затем то же значение, что и в подмаске №1, а потом `]`.

Если нужно удалить текст внутри тегов, но сами теги оставить, вы можете использовать [`String#replaceAllMapped`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.2.0/dart-core/String/replaceAllMapped.html):

```dart
final regex = RegExp(r'(\[(\w+)])[^]*?(\[\2])');
String text = "abc[a]NEED TO REMOVE THIS[a]some text[b]AND THIS[b]";
final result = text.replaceAllMapped(regex, (Match m) => "${m[1]}${m[3]}");
print(result); // => abc[a][a]some text[b][b]
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!